# Is predicting number of sales a Regression or Classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am a Machine Learning beginner who is currently doing Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera. In the lecture, he asked a simple question: Would you call the following a classification or regression problem?

You have a large inventory of identical items. You want to predict how many
of these items will sell over the next 3 months

I chose classification since I thought we are just predicting will sell (1) or won't sell (0). But he says it is a regression problem since there are thousands of identical items and it is a continuous output. I don't understand how it is a continuous output. Looks to me like a discrete output having thousands of values. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Note that the question was *You want to predict **how many** of these items will sell over the next 3 months*. That's just predicting the total number. Hence it's **regression**. It's not making an individual (1/0) prediction on each inventory item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how it is a continuous output. Looks to me like a discrete output having thousands of values.

Well, *continuous* output here has not the formal mathematical meaning; strictly speaking, you are correct in that your output (some integer value) is discrete, but this is not the point in this context.

The crucial difference that makes this a regression problem and not a classification one is that, in classification, the output is restricted to some (usually **few**) *predefined* values/levels; it is easy to see that this is not the case here, since a quantity sold can be in principle any (integer) value, and it makes no sense at all to consider, say, the values 18 and 19 as different *classes*.

It may also be useful to try to think of classification output as *categories* which, in general, may have no *ordinal* relation between them; from such a perspective, a difference between 18 and 19 can be considered the same with the difference between 18 and 856 (they are simply different categories); Intuitively, it should be obvious that, since we are interested in the exact amount sold, these differences are, well, very different between them, and we would very much prefer to mis-predict a "18" as a "19" rather than as a "856"...

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.